# Self Terminating a Class in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a class in VBA for Excel. I've a userform that opens and initiates the class and then the class is used to navigate a particular file layout. I've the basics implemented, however I want a simple way of exiting gracefully if someone runs the macro on another type of file.

When the class initialises it looks for particular cells/values and sets those ranges as member variables so, for example, if you run the macro on a blank file it crashes with a type Mismatch error.

I don't want complicated error handling or be constantly checking if every range exists as this macro is only designed to work with this particular layout, I want if it can't find all these ranges it displays a message box saying that the file layout looks wrong and gives the option to continue (and likely crash) or quit.

I've tried calling the Class_Terminate sub, Me.Terminate and Set Me = Nothing. Searching on Google and here doesn't bring up anything I've found useful.

Comment: Are you looking for `Unload Me`?

Comment: Thanks but no, I get a 'Can't Load or Unload this object' error when I try that. I think Unload Me terminates a userform but it doesn't seem to work on classes

Comment: In these cases an `Init()` method defined in your class can be used to return `False` if the initialization/setup fails for some reason.  If it returns False then exit the sub which called it, maybe with an appropriate error message (or the class can be responsible for showing the message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Option one:**

Use `End`. This is kind of an abrupt way to exit though, as you'll notice when you run the sample code.  The only output will be the `Debug.Print` from `Class_Initialize()`.  It's literally pulling the plug on your code.

(in a UserForm with a command button named "CommandButton1")

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim example As Class1
    Set example = New Class1
    Debug.Print "This will not execute."
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "This will not execute."
End Sub
```

In Class1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Couldn't validate."
    End   '<-- this is what you're looking for.
End Sub
```

Output:

> Couldn't validate.

### **Option two:**

Have the class unload the form.  This gives a much "cleaner" exit, and allows you to run any code that the form needs to shut down.  Note though that the order of execution may not be what you'd expect as the stack unwinds though.

In the form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim example As Class1
    Set example = New Class1
    Debug.Print "This will execute."
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "This will also execute, but not when you expect."
End Sub
```

In the class:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Couldn't validate."
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Output:

> Couldn't validate. 
>   This will also execute, but not when you expect. 
> This will execute.

Comment: I suspected that unloading the userform from the class instance might have a bit of a lag (presumably since the userform can't unload while one of its event handlers is running) but it is nice to see an example. Your option one might be what OP wants, but doesn't seem graceful. Maybe Tim William's suggestion in the comment is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks Comintern, ` End` was what I was looking for although as you and others point out it might not exactly be graceful. Unloading the userform from within the class is also interesting although it seems if I put it in the ` Class_Initialize` function the remainder of that function is executed and hence it still leads to it crashing if the layout is incorrect. I think the best solution is probably go back and do a few checks within the userform before the class gets initialized. Thanks to everyone who replied.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you want, but if I understand you correctly then it isn't possible because of how VBA uses reference-based garbage collection. There can be any number of variables that refer to an instance of a class. Class instances are destroyed when all variables referring to them are set equal to nothing or go out of scope. If an instance of class sets itself equal to nothing then everything that points to it would become dangling pointers. In order to keep reference counts in sync VBA would need to do something like locate everything that refers to the object and set them to nothing -- more trouble than it is worth. The caller that creates the reference should be the caller that destroys the reference -- anything else plays havoc with memory management.

On the other hand @rdhs might be correct that you are simply looking for the statement `Unload Me`. This would destroy the userform that creates the class instance, hence will destroy the class instance itself. If the `Unload` statement is in the class's code, you could try something like `Unload Userform1` (or whatever the name of the userform is).